# Unable to create server groups(create without tempplate) in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spinnaker

I am following the code labs *https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/gce-source-to-prod/* but I am facing a problem in creating server group in STEP-1. (Deploy stage). The page is getting loaded for infinite time. I think I can say It is not going beyond that point. I am able to come up to this step only if I am using AZURE or any other local machines. If I use Google Cloud Instance to do SSH tunneling I am not even able to create a application. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do some additional troubleshooting to determine where the problem is.  For example, run netstat on the machine to see whether it's listening on port 9000.  See if you can create a firewall rule allowing inbound traffic on that port and then try to connect directly without using the SSH tunnel.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think the problem was with the image. When I used Cloud launcher it worked.